Correct flow for retrieving access token of OIDC provider using Firebase Auth in Flutter
I'm using Firebase Auth in my app and I'm signing in using an OAuthProvider like this:
final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(
  OAuthProvider('oidc.my-oidc-provider')
    ..setScopes([
      'openid',
      'profile',
      'email',
      'offline_access',
      // Some more custom scopes
    ]),
);

I can get the access token issued by the OIDC provider from the credential like this:
final accessToken = credential.credential?.accessToken;

and store it in some provider (I'm using Riverpod) to use it later to authenticate requests to my backend.
However, I'm wondering how I should handle refreshes in this case. I don't see a way to get this access token again from the user callback parameter of methods such as authStateChanges, idTokenChanges or userChanges.
I have found the reauthenticateWithProvider method on user, which does give me the credential again but I'm not sure if I should be using it in this case.
Some guidance on how to keep the access token up to date would be greatly appreciated!
PS: I've noticed that when I call the signOut method on the FirebaseAuth instance, the user is not actually signed out of my OIDC provider. The next time I sign in, the username/password prompt is skipped, suggesting that the user was still signed in.
I'm not sure if these issues are related to each other. If not I will make a separate question.
